# Get kendo dropdownlist value/text/index in selected kendo grid mvvm

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-dropdown, kendo-mvvm

I'm able to add a kendo dropdownlist into kendo grid by template scenario below:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="ddlGrid">
    <input data-role="dropdownlist"
       data-text-field="Text"
       data-value-field="Value"
       data-bind="source: actionSource, events: { change: onChange}"/>
</script>
<div class="demo-section">
<div class="k-content" style="width: 100%">
    <div id="grid"
         data-role="grid"
         data-sortable="true"
         data-selectable="true"
         data-columns="[
            { field: 'ProductID' },
            { field: 'ProductName' },
            { field: 'UnitPrice' },
            { field: 'UnitsInStock' },
            { field: 'Discontinued' },
            { title: 'Action', template: kendo.template($('#ddlGrid').html())} ]"
         data-bind="source: dataSource, event">
    </div>
</div>
```

However, the problem is how to access that dropdownlist to get it value/text/index.
So far I can get the selected row data using this approach:

```
var onClick = function (event, delegate) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
  var selectedRow = grid.select();
  var dataItem = grid.dataItem(selectedRow);
  if (selectedRow.length > 0)
    delegate(dataItem);
  else
    alert("Please select a row.");
  };

var viewModel = new kendo.data.ObservableObject({
    dataSource: productDatasource,
    actionSource: actionDataSource,

    onChange: function (event) {
        onClick(event, function (dataItem) {
            alert(dataItem.ProductID + " " + dataItem.ProductName);
        });            
    },

});
```

Here is the [JSFiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/komangmahendra/hLG98/10/)

Please help me, I'm stuck.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access DropDownList text and value using:

```
var value = event.sender.value();
var text = event.sender.text();
```

inside your `onChange` function:

```
onChange: function (event) {
    alert ("Text/Value : " + event.sender.text() + "/" + event.sender.value());
    onClick(event, function (dataItem) {
        alert(dataItem.ProductID + " " + dataItem.ProductName);
    });            
},
```

**BUT** I'm actually not sure why are you defining `onClick` and all that complex code when you can get the dataItem simply doing:

```
var viewModel = new kendo.data.ObservableObject({
    dataSource: productDatasource,
    actionSource: actionDataSource,

    onChange: function (event) {
        alert ("Text/Value : " + event.sender.text() + "/" + event.sender.value());
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        var dataItem = grid.dataItem($(event.sender.wrapper).closest("tr"));
        alert(dataItem.ProductID + " " + dataItem.ProductName);
    },

});
kendo.bind($("#grid"), viewModel);
```

See it here : http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/hLG98/12/

Comment: grid.dataItem($(event.sender.wrapper).closest("tr")); it took me so much time to reach here. wanted to get select get grid row on SELECT event of combobox (which is there as templete cell). thanks for post